# Using Factor Scores for further Regression Analysis

Tags: multiple-regression, categorical-data, ordinal-data

I am in the midst of a research programme on standardisation and ICT in the real estate sector, as part of which a web-based survey is underway and I am nearing completion of the data collection stage.

1. The web-based survey has collected data on dependent and independent variables.
2. Both the dependent (predicted) and independent (predictor) variables are on ordinal scale (respectively 1-4 and 1-5).
3. There are 14 independent variables with substantial correlation among them (on an average in the range of 0.1 to 0.5).
4. My ultimate objective is to relate the independent variables (or factors derived from it) to the dependent one and extract the correlation coefficients.
5. The survey has yielded values for the dependent and all the independent variables on the respective ordinal scales.

Work performed so far is as follows: 
For the first step I have used factor analysis on the 14 independent variables and have meaningfully narrowed down to four factors using SPSS (with Varimax rotation). For each of the factors I also have factor scores that all have decimal values (unlike the primary independent variables which were integers on 1-5 scale) and also in the negative for several records.

Now I want to regress the dependent variable on the four derived factors (each of which I have meaningfully named) using an appropriate regression methodology (I had ordinal regression in mind). Can someone please guide me on the way forward. I will be grateful if someone could also suggest papers that capture similar research efforts in the past.